# How safe is it to travel to Ethiopia?

Tags: nigerian-citizens, ethiopia

How safe is it at this point to travel to Ethiopia? I would like to spend a month in Addis Ababa? Please I would like to know the risks as well as other info that might seem helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not that safe; but everything is relative.

On a scale of 4, the USA department of state lists Ethiopia a 2, "Exercise Increased Caution".

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/ethiopia-travel-advisory.html

The [UK foreign affair](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ethiopia/safety-and-security) department :

"Addis Ababa and other major urban areas are comparatively safe compared to many African cities. However, the British Embassy has received increased reports of foreign nationals being targeted by groups of youths or scam artists. Petty theft and mugging is on the rise. There has been a smaller number of more serious incidents, including sexual harassment of women and robberies."

Canada has the same safety warnings as the UK.

Sooo, if you want to go, it should be OK, but it always depends on your own personal level of sens of safety.

personally, as a white male, I would probably not go.